# Does AcitivtyAnimation don't work when there is a fragment

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have an Activity in Which I am trying to use Activity Transition but The Explode Transition is not working for some reason What I have is an Activity which has Exploded Animation and I am inflating fragment inside it.

The Fragment has a RecyclerView which has a gridLayoutManager what I want my Explode Animation to do is Explode the Grids of Image when Activity Enters and Leaves but For some reason it is not Working??

My Activity Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_folder_view);
    setUpWindowAnimation();


@TargetApi(21)
private void setUpWindowAnimation() {
    Explode explode = new Explode();
    explode.setDuration(1000);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
    getWindow().setReenterTransition(explode);
}
```